# Android get web page source

Tags: android, url, web

I want to get the source code of a web page that the users enters. When he presses the button, he should see the source in a `TextView`. This is my code:

```
final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    URL url = null;
                    url = new URL(myEditText.getText().toString());
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        myTextView.append(line);

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("ERR",e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
```

When I run it I get a NullPointerException at

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

.-->Println needs a message.

I don't know what is wrong, since this is from a video tutorial. I have written `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in Manifest so, everything should be allright.

Comment: I suspect that your URL is null.  Does that need to be in an EditText and can you verify its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
url = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

if it works then you need to set validation for like **isValidUrl()** ?

Because user may have entered wrong URL.

Comment: How i get just some line of html-source code of webpage ? if i get full source page it may get so much time and i dont need to get all line, can you help me? thx very much

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(myEditText.getText()))
             url = new URL(myEditText.getText().toString());
else
url="";
```

or if you are using latest version check StrictMode and remove it

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

also check the android is network available or not